# Stop BACK button closing jQuery mobile Popups

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'd like the browser BACK button (and BKSP which is BACK anyway) to stop closing down my jQuery Mobile Popups.  Here's how I configure the popups:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="timeout-popup" data-theme="c" data-overlay-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all ui-content" data-dismissible="false" data-history="false">
    <div style="min-width:250px;">
        <div style="width:100%; display:block;"><img src="/mobile/images/logo.png" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></div>
        <h2>Session Expired</h2>
        <p>Your session has expired.</p>
        <button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-e ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check" id="btn-timeout-login">Click to Login Again</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's how I'm making the popup appear:

```
$('#timeout-popup').popup('open',{transition:'fade'});
```

I thought the data-history="false" was supposed to prevent the back button from doing anything but it's not.  Any suggestions?